# What .net libraries can I use to synchronize in-memory object graph over multiple machines?

Tags: database, .net, notification, synchronization

**A task to accomplish**

Replace my read queries to a DB with requests to an in-memory snapshot of said DB to improve my server's performance. I've a DB of a very moderate size, with a few write requests and limited number of clients.

**Set of features the library in question should have**

1. available in .net
2. compatible with MS SQL Server
3. provides database change broadcasting mechanism
4. is able to populate memory with objects from a DB
5. and keep them in sync as records in the DB change
6. works with user defined classes,
7. -or- provides machinery to generate said classes form a DB schema

**Not a solutions to my problem**

1. Oracle, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL and IBM DB2, etc.
2. NHibernate, EntityFramework, etc.

**Also**

1. if you only know some good terms to google for, shoot